# Asus 1018p battery light blinking and not charging

Tags: battery, ubuntu-11.04, charging

I recently got myself a netbook (Asus 1018pb) and its really good. I have not used it for about a week and when I tried to turn it on today it seemed to be completely drained out of charge. I plugged in the charger and started working but after sometime I noticed that the battery percentage hasn't gone up by 1% even on the top. When I click on the battery , it says `laptop battery (estimating...)`

And in addition to this, the charge light keeps blinking.

Has anybody else faced this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its now charging !

Turns out , the battery was COMPLETELY drained out ! I just left the charger on for a bit (about half an hour) and now its charging . The battery indicator also has updated to say that it will need about 2 hours to complete !

So i guess the answer is : **Patience is a virtue** :)